# What is the role of u0X directory in Hadoop clusters?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and Linux. I am following a tutorial to build a simple 3-node cluster and after succesfully installing a pseduo-distributed one I now need to reconfigure it to fully distributed.

I got to the point where I need to provide redundancy for the fsimage file. So according to the tutorial I need to edit the `hdfs-site.xml` in this manner:

Current setting (pseudo-distributed)

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
```

Change to (fully-distributed)

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///u01/dfs/namenode,file:///u02/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>
```

This seems straightforward but to a new linux user it raises a question mark.

What is the meaning of `u01` and `u02`? Are these just new directories that I need to create? Are there any implicit configurations assoicated with them? The tutroial does not provide more info so I am guessing there is some common knowledge that I lack. Am I supposed to just create the directories, modify the xml file and move along?

Any explanation about what is a `uXX` directory in general and how it relates to Hadoop cluster would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `dfs.namenode.name.dir` determines where in the local filesystem, the HDFS namenode has to store the persistent HDFS metadata (fsimage and edits). Atleast one directory path is required as the value for this property.

If you provide a comma separated list of directory paths, the namenode will try to replicate the same metadata across all those paths. It is meant only for redundancy.

The directory paths can be of any structure provided the user running the namenode process has access to them. Here `uXX` is purely meant to differentiate that they are different directory paths.

This property also accepts remote (like NFS) filesystem directory paths in addition to the local FS.